# Having trouble vertically centering an h1 element and an input element

Tags: html, css, alignment

Goal: I am trying to set up an input on a side project I'm working on where the user inputs some information. Currently I have it set up with the label of the input in the left most bubble followed by two text input bubbles.

Problem: The input fields are about 5 pixels bellow the bubble that is labeling them and I can't figure out how to correct that.

Notes: I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS and am completely self taught so if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do please let me new. Bellow is the section that is giving me trouble

```css
.inputConatiner {
  height: 75px;
}

.textContainer {
  height: 75px;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 0px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.label {
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans";
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(104, 255, 144);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Side Project</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="#" name="getStudentInfo">
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">Enter Your Name</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">1A Class</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your snippet below. I think this is what you are looking for and was simply fixed by using `vertical-align: middle;` on the `label`. Not sure of what you are using this for, however, I would suggest perhaps using a framework such as https://getbootstrap.com/. Most frameworks will have great foundation blocks across all screen sizes and devices (as in the snippet below, you'll have to view in full screen, otherwise it is a mess. Currently, from a UI focus, this implementation is very limited by not being responsive.

Hope this helps.

```css
.inputConatiner {
  height: 75px;
}

.textContainer {
  height: 75px;
  width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 0px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.label {
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans";
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(104, 255, 144);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Side Project</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="#" name="getStudentInfo">
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">Enter Your Name</h1>
      <div class="textContainer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputConatiner">
      <h1 class="label">1A Class</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` for `.textContainer` to solve 5px problem.

Please see this document for [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed in your HTML code is your second `.inputContainer` is missing a `.textContainer`. Since you've said that you're fairly new to HTML and CSS, I suggest that you use basic properties like `float` to make elements stacked side by side and `margin` for spacing/aligning.

```css
.inputConatiner {
  height: auto;
}

/* Without this, the layout would be ruined because of float */
.inputConatiner:before, .inputConatiner:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.inputConatiner:after {
  clear: both;
}

.textContainer {
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left; /* This makes the elements stacked side by side */
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: 0px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.label {
  width: 270px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans";
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left; /* This makes the elements stacked side by side */
  background-color: rgb(104, 255, 144);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#" name="getStudentInfo">
  <div class="inputConatiner">
    <h1 class="label">Enter Your Name</h1>
    <div class="textContainer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First" required />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last" required />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputConatiner">
    <h1 class="label">1A Class</h1>
    <div class="textContainer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Class" required />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Teacher" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```